# How to Disable button when dropdown is empty in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to check whether the dropdown is empty.
If not empty, enable the submit button.
If empty, disable the submit button.
Below is my html

```
<form  [formGroup]="addTaskForm"  (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite animal" [formControl]="animalControl" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
      {{animal.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="animalControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an animal</mat-error>

</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [formControl]="foodControl" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="foodControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an food</mat-error>

</mat-form-field>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>

<button type="submit"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial [disabled]="!formCtrl.form.valid">submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-olzhfg-z7e6ix?file=app/dialog-overview-example.html)

help me out

Comment: There are multiple console errors in your demo that will probably lead you to a solution, if you correct them.

Comment: i am not getting any error in console

Comment: you definitely should be, if your code matches the demo you posted.  if you aren't, then you probably should consider fixing the demo before asking for further help.

Comment: can you please help me out @Claies

Comment: I have updated my answer it is working please, try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, Try below code it is working,

```
<form [formGroup]="addTaskForm"  (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite animal" [formControl]="animalControl" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
      {{animal.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="animalControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an animal</mat-error>

</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [formControl]="foodControl" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="foodControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an food</mat-error>

</mat-form-field>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>

<button type="submit"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial [disabled]="foodControl.hasError('required') || animalControl.hasError('required')">submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: where you bind selected value in dropdown

Comment: my expecttation before submit form all dropdown should be filled

Comment: no its not working only its checking foodControl i want to check both i updated here demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-olzhfg-jhdvdn?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html

Comment: i have changed my answer now try it

Comment: need one more help if i submit how can i get selected dropdown values in console(submit() {
      console.log(this.addTaskForm.value);
  })   .   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-olzhfg-awghxy?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts